# PHP SQL User Profile Completeness calculation not working

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to show a profile completeness bar on the users account and the progress bar is showing but it's not adding the number values in order to calculate the percentage of completed fields ie: 
if($row['title'] != '')
$completedTitle = 20;

My shortened code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,name,surname,identityno,gender FROM cic_candidates WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

$maximumPoints  = 100;

 {
if($row['title'] != '')
$completedTitle = 20;

if($row['name'] != '')
$completedName = 20;

if($row['surname'] != '')
$completedSurname = 20;

if($row['identityno'] != '')
$dcompletedIdentityno = 20;

if($row['gender'] != '')
$completedGender = 20;

 }

$percentage = ($dcompletedTitle+$completedName+$completedSurname+$completedIdentityno+$completedGender)*$maximumPoints/100;

echo "".$percentage."%";

?>
```

The percentage shows in the echo but the total is wrong - it's not taking the values of 20 points for each field that is completed and including them in the "addition" part of the percentage calculation. Please can you tell me where I'm going wrong - I've been trying to figure this out for 4 days and have googled this and read over 2000 forums but can't find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think It's (sum)*100/$maximumpoints and what is the current result

Comment: `$dcompletedTitle` --> `$completedTitle`.  You have a typo in your calculation, by my reading.

Comment: 2 typos indeed. dcompleteidentity....

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my thread but my code in DW doesn't have typo - good spot! :)

Comment: Where do I put the (sum) because if I add it in before *$maximumPoints/100; it shows a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting it all wrong from your condition, try this... it worked for me

```
$sql = "SELECT title,name,surname,identityno,gender FROM cic_candidates WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $DBconnection->query($sql); 
$maxvalue  = 100;
$point = 0;
if ($result) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['title'] != ''){
            $point1  = $point+20;
        }elseif($row['title'] == ''){
            $point1 = $point+=0;
        }

        if($row['name'] != ''){
            $point2 = $point+20;
        }elseif($row['name'] == ''){
            $point2 = $point+=0;
        }

        if($row['surname'] != ''){
            $point3 = $point+20;
        }elseif($row['surname'] == ''){
            $point3 = $point+0;
        }

        if($row['identityno'] != ''){
            $point4 = $point+20;
        }elseif($row['identityno'] == ''){
            $point4 = $point+0;
        }

        if($row['gender'] != ''){
            $point5 = $point+=20;
        }elseif($row['gender'] == ''){
            $point5 = $point+0;
        }
        // otherwise
     }
}else{
    echo "error completing query";
}
$pint  = $point1+$point2+$point3+$point4+$point5;
$percentage = ($pint*100)/100;
echo $percentage."%";
```

Answer (score 0):

use {} around single quotes in query

```
    <?php 
// fisrt select database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title,name,surname,identityno,gender FROM cic_candidates WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1"); 
//use of MYSQL_QUERY is deprecated so don't use it 
//use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query
if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query " . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

$maximumPoints  = 100;
$point = 0;
 {
if($row['title'] != '')
$point+=20;

if($row['name'] != '')
$point+=20;

if($row['surname'] != '')
$point+=20;

if($row['identityno'] != '')
$point+=20;

if($row['gender'] != '')
$point+=20;

 }

$percentage = ($point*$maximumPoints)/100;
echo $percentage."%";

?>
```

Comment: I copied your code and it still shows 0% - do you think it's reading the value of "20" correctly?

Comment: @user2733533 I have edited the answer. After running the above code what output you are getting???

Comment: Title (field completed) - Name (field completed) - Surname (field completed) - Identityno (field empty) - Gender (field empty) so the result should be 60% complete.

Comment: I changed them all to smaller case and the result is still showing 0% complete...

Comment: @user2733533 just echo '$point'. and if it is showing 0 then check whether 'id' which is in your query is a valid(i.e. it exits and it's other value are set(title,name,surname etc))

Comment: I changed it to $point and it still shows 0. The id, title, name, surname, identityno and gender exist in the database table - the first 3 fields have information in them and the last 2 fields are empty... no errors are coming up it just shows 0%...your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @user2733533 is 'id' and 'identityno' are different field in your table??